# Importing custom module cleanly

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to import a class from my submodule without having to use the `from submodule.submodule import Class` syntax. Instead I would just like to do `from submodule import Class` like a normal Python3 module.

I feel this should have been answered a million times, and while there are several similarly named questions on SO, none of them provide a clear, simple solution with a bare-bones example.

I'm trying to get the simplest test working with this setup:

```
.
├── main.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

In my `test` module, I have the following contents:

**test.py**

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')
```

**__init__.py**

```
from test import Test
__all__ = ['Test']
```

In the upper-level **main.py** I have the following:

```
from test import Test
Test()
```

When I try to run `main.py` I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Test'
```

I know I could replace the import statement in `main.py` with `from test.test import Test`, but my understanding was that one of the points of `__init__.py` was to make submodules accessible at the package level (with `__all__` allowing to import all with `from test import *`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PEP 404](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/):

> In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer
>   available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are
>   supported. In addition, star imports (e.g. from x import *) are only
>   permitted in module level code.

If you change `__init__.py` to:

```
from test.test import Test
__all__ = ['Test']
```

then your code works:

```
$ python3 main.py
hello
```

But now it works only on `python3` (and your original code works only on `python2`).
To have code that works on both lines of python, we have to use *explicit relative import*:

```
from .test import Test
__all__ = ['Test']
```

Code execution:

```
$ python2 main.py 
hello
$ python3 main.py 
hello
```